# Como adicionar apenas um produto de cada vez no carrinho e calcular o total

Tags: javascript

estou desenvolvendo um cardápio digital e estou com dificuldade de como fazer a parte que o cliente adiciona o produto no carrinho, seleciona as quantidades do produto e calcular automaticamente o subtotal e o total, gostaria de saber como posso fazer ?

Comment: Olá Pedro! Seja benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Comment: Boa tarde Pedro, de fato a sua pergunta é muito abrangente, o processo de carrinho pode possuir diferentes abordagens, envolver diversas tabelas, procesos e validações. Primeiro você deve entender sobre o seu processo, desenhe ele usando diagramas UML, valide se de fato faz sentido, se tiver dúvidas se tal processo faz sentido, pergunte aqui, coloque o seu desenho explique sua estratégia/processo e garanto que o pessoal vai lhe ajudar. Depois disso você começa a programar, com o diagrama pronto fica bem mais fácil.

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta é um tanto genérica, então aí vai uma resposta genérica em 3 passos (mas que espero que seja útil :))

Digamos que seu cardápio de produtos tenha esse formato aqui:

```
const productsMenu = {
 prod01: {name: 'camisa', value:100},
 prod02: {name: 'calça', value:200},
 prod03: {name: 'boné', value:50}
}
```

1. Precisamos primeiro de um array pra receber os produtos que o usuário vai comprar, isto é, o famoso "carrinho" de compras.
   Vamos então criar nossa lista de produtos (que começa vazia)

```
const cart = []
```

2. Fazemos então uma function para adicionar produtos ao cart

```
function addProductToCart(product, amount) {
  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    cart.push(product)
  }
}
```

*** Dispare essa função sempre q o usuário adicionar algo ao carrinho, passando por parâmetro o produto e a quantidade. Por exemplo:

```
addProductToCart(productsMenu['prod01'], 4)
addProductToCart(productsMenu['prod02'], 2)
addProductToCart(productsMenu['prod03'], 1)
```

Cada chamada ao addProductToCart vai "empurrar" novos produtos pro array cart. No nosso caso, as chamadas acima deixarão nosso array cart assim:

```
[
 {name:"camisa",value:100},
 {name:"camisa",value:100},
 {name:"camisa",value:100},
 {name:"camisa",value:100},
 {name:"calça",value:200}, 
 {name:"calça",value:200},
 {name:"boné", value:50}
]
```

3. Agora precisamos de uma função para somar os values de cada product do nosso array cart. O método reduce é perfeito pra isso!

```
function getCartTotal(userCart) {
  return userCart.reduce((acc, next) => {
    return acc += next.value
  }, 0)
}
```

O Array.reduce percorre cada elemento do array e possui um acumulador, que no nosso caso, usamos pra "acumular" o valor de cada product. Ao final, retornamos o valor acumulado de todos os values do nosso array cart

```
getCartTotal(cart)

// 850
```

Nessa solução usamos apenas um pouquinho do poder do reduce. Lógicas bem mais sofisticadas podem ser criadas dentro de uma função reduce, vale a pena estudar isso! Na minha opinião o segredo pra compreender melhor esse método está no terceiro parâmetro que passamos pra função, que representa o valor inicial do acumulador. No nosso caso, esse parâmetro é um número 0, mas poderia ser um array, um objeto...Enfim, fica a dica! Espero que ajude.